Problem with "filler variables" and their syntax
So I'm trying to solve a problem of a past olympiad where you basically take a string i.e. HLOEL- and a number P=3 and it outputs HELLO-, it works by sorting the letters of the string into groups(rows) of P and then getting the first letter of each group, then the second letter of each group... all the way to the last letter of each group.
H L O E L -  --> (HE)(LL)(O-)=HELLO-
My problem is that in my code I created a variable "ix" where i is in a for loop and thus creating P variables that is each a group and then I put another for loop where it takes column by column so it outputs the correct string at the end. But it only takes the first group (ix, i=1) and outputs the letters in the group.
Keep in mind that I don't want a solution to the problem in general but just a fix if there is to my code.
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int P, i, z;
    string S, L;

    cin >> P >> S;

    for (i = 1; i <= P; i++) {
        string ix = S.substr(0, P);
        S.erase(0, P);
       
        for (z = P; z >= 1; z--) {
            i = P - z + 1;
            cout << ix.at(P - z);
        }
    }
}

input:
3
HLOEL-
Expected output:
HELLO-
actual output:
HLO

I see groups of 2, but P is supposed to be 3.

"My problem is that in my code I created a variable "ix" where i is in a for loop and thus creating P variables that is each a group and then I put another for loop where it takes column by column so it outputs the correct string at the end." -- Fifty-one words is a rather long sentence (and this one is hard to parse). Try breaking this up into multiple sentences.

"H L O E L - --> (HE)(LL)(O-)=HELLO-" -- Probably should include another step: "HLOEL-" --> (HLO)(EL-) --> (HE)(LL)(O-) --> "HELLO-"

Have you done any debugging on your own? I don't see anything going on here that would not be fairly easy to find by stepping through the code with a debugger or possibly by rubber duck debugging. Another option would be diagnostic outputs, such as outputting ix in each iteration of the outer loop. What were the results of your debugging?

While your code does not compile, it's clear that you're overthinking the problem and solving your approach is not really worthwhile. There's no need to generate or access substrings at all.
Having read in the initial string, you simply need to iterate over it with a couple of loops.
Starting at index 0, print the first letter, then increment by P. Now do that but start with progressively one further into the string.
void print_string(int p, std::string s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < s.length(); j += p) {
            std::cout << s[j];
        }
    }
}


Thanks a lot for the solution. I had thought about doing it in this way but I wasn't sure how to do it so I ended up making it a lot more complicated than it is. However  I still don't understand why my attempt doesn't work.

Tactical note: See how Chris doesn't define i until he uses it in the loop?  This prevents i from leaking out of the loop and causing bugs later. It's a trick well worth stealing and using yourself.

The main idea in question is about coversion of a row-major matrix into a colomn-major one. Since you are at the beginning of your learning, I suggest to start with newest C++ features. Remember "raw loops are unnamed algorithms". From C++20 onward we are eventually capable of composing known algorithms into lazy expressions using standard library:
#include <ranges>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main{
    std::size_t row_count{};
    std::string char_mat{};

    std::cin << row_count;
    getline(std::cin, char_mat);

    //bring views into main function scope:
    using namespace std::views;

    //create a view by composing algorithms:
    auto const trans_view
       = iota(0,size(char_mat)) /* count[0,size) */
       | transform ( [chars = char_mat | all](auto cols)
         /* skip front elements: */
         { return chars | drop(cols); } )
       | stride(row_count) /* pick first one, every 'n' elements*/
       | join /* flatten a 2d view into 1D */;


    //print without extra memory allocation:
    std::ranges::copy( trans_view
                     , std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout) );

    //Or first copy data:
    /*
    auto const transposed 
       = trans_view
       | std::ranges::to<std::string>();

    std::cout << transposed;
    */

    return 0;
};

Some may argue that this stuff is overkill for beginner level programs. But I believe this is the kind of stuff that should be placed at the beginning of a C++ programming textbook. It enables faster conversion between python and C++ code with less pain, and each line clarifies the intent without too much effort.
One benefit of this style is avoiding explicit index acquisition on string/vector/array elements, thereby skipping some well-known pitfalls such as index-out-of-bounds. The method shown here can later be deviced to transpose matrices stored in std::vector or similar containers; It is bound to character strings.
If you later decide to optimize the code, this algorithm oriented approach creates a good foundation. It is always possible to convert this snippet into raw loops and lower level constructs, but refactoring the other way around is difficult. In the end I don't mean to provide the best or final answer to OP question. This post intends to demonstrate an alternative approach which may broaden the horizon for someone entering C++ domain.
